# When using Combines .first(where: ) operator, why is the value that is printed out H, and not O, in my example code? Thank you

Tags: swift, combine

I am asking a question regarding Combines `.first(where: )` method. When looking at my code, I use Hello World as the reference by which to check if it contains the values emitted by my publisher.

Why is H the first value thats emitted, when in reality O gets printed first?

I hope my question is not confusing. If you read the code it should make much more sense. Thanks!

```
// 1 Create a publisher that emits four letters.
    let publisher = ["J", "O", "H", "N"].publisher
    
    // 2 Use the first(where:) operator to find the first letter contained in Hello World and then print it out.
    publisher
        .print("publisher")
        .first(where: { "Hello World".contains($0) })
        .sink(receiveValue: { print("First match is \($0)") })
        .store(in: &subscriptions)
```

And this is what get's printed to the console:

```
publisher: receive subscription: (["J", "O", "H", "N"]) 
publisher: request unlimited 
publisher: receive value: (J) 
publisher: receive value: (O) 
publisher: receive value: (H) 
publisher: receive cancel First match is H
```

Shouldn't the first match be O? Since it's hell**o** world?
I understand it also contains **h**ello, but **o** get's emitted before h.

Thanks once more.

Comment: Nothing to do with Combine. It's just a matter of knowing what a character is. "O" is not "o". So "Hello World" does not contain "J" or "O". It does contain "H". So "H" is the first one that meets the condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Combine, so all that scaffolding just boils down to:

```
print("Hello World".contains("J")) // false
print("Hello World".contains("O")) // false
print("Hello World".contains("H")) // true
print("Hello World".contains("N")) // false
```

Which just happens because `"o" != "O"` and `"H" == "H"`. That is, character equality is sensitive to capitalization.

Comment: You meant `"o" != "O"`